# Use constant value as typescript key name

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-navigation

I am trying to deine and configure all of my screens for `react-navigation` in a single file a bit like this:

```
export const SCREEN_1: ScreenConfig = { path: '/screen-1', component: ... };
export const SCREEN_2: ScreenConfig = { path: '/screen-2', component: ... };
```

This then allows me to render and navigate to the screens like this:

```
import * as screens from './screens';
screens.map(screen => <Screen name={screen.path} component={screen.component} />);
...
import { SCREEN_1 } from './screens'
navigation.navigate(SCREEN_1.path, props);
```

I now also wanna add type checking for the props passed to the navigate function. `react-navigation` allows me to define types like this:

```
type ScreenParams = {
  '/screen-1': Screen1Props,
  '/screen-2': Screen2Props,
}
```

Is there a way to automatically generate the ScreenParams type withouth having to define the path in a second location.
The best I got so far is something like this:

```
type ScreenParams = {
  '/screen-1': React.ComponentProps<SCREEN_1.component>,
  '/screen-2': React.ComponentProps<SCREEN_2.component>,
}
```

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link)](https://tsplay.dev/NBP4bW), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing without unrelated errors or undeclared values or types. This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: This question seems like it depends on whatever `ScreenConfig` is, but you will likely not want to annotate your exported values as that because the compiler will forget the specific `path` string literals (like saying `const foo: string = "hello"` and then expecting the compiler to remember that `foo` is `"hello"` instead of `"goodbye"`; it was annotated as `string` and that's all the compiler will remember). Instead you probably want `export const SCREEN_1 = {...} as const` and then you can manipulate the type. But in order for me to go further I need clean example code that works in an IDE.